# File upload issue. using the w3school tutorial

Tags: php

I look at w3school tutorial for upload a file. I can understand the code. The first 2 simply version of the code works, while this doesn't.

```
  <?php
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
     {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
     }
    else
    {
    echo "Invalid file";
       }
       ?>
```

I have a problem, if i use this code to upload a file i Always get Invalid file response.

EDIT:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to upload and what file size?

Comment: Never trust w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/ Try this tutorial for file upload instead: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Comment: Where is your html code ? And do not refer to `w3schools` for learning, specially for PHP.

Comment: lol thank you, i Always based on w3school since now

Answer (score 1):

Also check Folder permission. Upload folder permission should be 777.

Comment: i am trying it on a webserver for now ty the same

Answer (score 0):

this code only uploads images.

you cannot upload same files that are already uploaded.

you cannot upload files more than 20KB.

make sure you have a directory named 'upload' in your source folder

Comment: u missed to write "if there is no such directory for 'upload/' " then??

Comment: try to elaborate all aspects for question when u will post answer next time..it may have chances for some wrong html code too..